# oauth consumer key and consumer secret registration

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, facebook-oauth

i am doing a project on oauth. i have to ask the user to login to the third party site(google,facebook,msn,linkein) via oauth.i am in developing stage of the project.

for facebook i went to the site and get registered to

https://developers.facebook.com/apps

As i am in developing stage of the project i have to use certain steps for this.it is as per the following link.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/samples/canvas/

my project is with java web environment with tomcat.

in the above link it has said that the requirements as python.

any way i can't find the canvas page in the facebook site..i am unable to find facebook integration tab also.

any help...
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solved this. Ultimately my aim is to get the facebook oauth provider to give the details of the users.

we have to register our application at the link 1.

Here it will ask the phone message code.But you will not recieve the message code.Keep on trying that you will definitely get at later time(it means that you may get after 1 day or 2 days.)But everyday you have to try that.it will take 4 days around.

Then it will give the api key and secret and if your application is developing stage there is a option of putting the callback url as http://localhost:8080/

take the code from the scribe by great person fernadez pablo.

then execute the code in eclipse and start the tomcat server
you will get the verification code as like this

http://localhost:8080/code="blabla"

copy the blabla and put in verification code.

you will get the user details.

Now i have to turn this application to web form.

Thank you